# Include resize in image_tag with id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minimagick

I use `mini_magick` for resize image.

**model**

```
def large input
    return self.images[input].variant(resize: '400x400!').processed
end
```

**But how to include resize in this image_tag :**

```
<%= image_tag(projet.images[0]) if projet.images.length > 0 %>
```

That's how i usually use it:

```
<% (0...@projet.images.count).each do |image| %>
    <%= image_tag(@projet.large(image))%>
<% end %>
```

But today i would like to use it for an image_tag with id.

I try :

```
<%= image_tag(projet.images[0].variant(resize_to_fit: [400, 400])) if projet.images.length > 0 %>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution :

```
 <%= image_tag url_for(projet.images[0].variant(resize: "400x400")) if projet.images.length > 0 %>
```

with class :

```
<%= image_tag(url_for(projet.images[0].variant(resize: "400x400")), class:"background") if projet.images.length > 0 %>
```